# I am trying to figure out closing a Modal Box Dynamically using jquery without a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out a Modal Box Dynamically using jQuery without a form.

```html
 <a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
  <div> <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>

    <h2>Modal Box</h2>

    <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
    <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Where is the code you tried?

Comment: No!! its not a bootstrap one. I am trying with CSS HTML and JQUERY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below code it will help you

```
 $('#openModal').modal('hide');
 $('#openModal').modal().hide();
 $('#openModal').removeClass('show');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```